# javascript - how to try catch an async function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have a function that uses axios to make a network request:

```
async loadAvailableDates(startDate, endDate, bounds) {
    const polygon = this.getDatePolygon(bounds);
    let indexUrl = `${this.baseUrl}index/v2/search`;
    var url = `${indexUrl}?timefrom=${startDate}&timeto=${endDate}T23:59:59&&maxcount=31`;
    const res = await this.httpClient.post(url, polygon);
    const availableDates = [];
    res.data.tiles.map(tile => {
      availableDates.push({
        date: tile.sensingTime.split("T")[0],
        cloudCoverage: tile.cloudCoverPercentage
      });
    });
    return availableDates;
  }
```

Then I am calling this function in another block of code:

```
const dates = await this.props.uiStore
        .loadAvailableDates(endDate, startDate, managedParcel.bounds)
```

Now I would like implement error handling on this function in case the network request fails (instead of an error I would like to return an empty array).

I tried doing this:

```
const dates = await this.props.uiStore
        .loadAvailableDates(endDate, startDate, managedParcel.bounds)
        .catch(e => return [])
```

But it does not work.

Do I need to wrap the network request in the `loadAvailableDates` function in a try/catch block, or is there a way to do it in the function call?

Comment: Because catch like that works only on promises.

Comment: @azurinko an async function *is* a promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function : "When an async function is called, it returns a Promise. When the async function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the returned value.  When the async function throws an exception or some value, the Promise will be rejected with the thrown value."

Comment: Yea, return value, but to .catch and .then, you must return a PROMISE.

Comment: It's in promise prototype, not in value prototype...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use normal try-catch blocks or the promise-feature `.catch()`

[Here's a writeup on it](http://blog.grossman.io/how-to-write-async-await-without-try-catch-blocks-in-javascript/)

```
let dates = [];
try {
    dates = await this.props.uiStore
        .loadAvailableDates(endDate, startDate, managedParcel.bounds)
} catch (e) {
    dates = [];
}
return dates;
```

-- edit

also try this:

```
async loadAvailableDates(startDate, endDate, bounds) {
    try {        
        const polygon = this.getDatePolygon(bounds);
        let indexUrl = `${this.baseUrl}index/v2/search`;
        var url = `${indexUrl}?timefrom=${startDate}&timeto=${endDate}T23:59:59&&maxcount=31`;
        const res = await this.httpClient.post(url, polygon);
        const availableDates = [];
        res.data.tiles.map(tile => {
            availableDates.push({
                date: tile.sensingTime.split("T")[0],
                cloudCoverage: tile.cloudCoverPercentage
            });
        });
        return availableDates;
    } catch (e) {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, when I put the try/catch statement into the loadAvailableDates function, I am still getting the error in the console, and it blocks the function execution? But when I put the try catch on the actual function call it executes correctly.

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič that's really strange. I honestly haven't had much practice with using `async` myself, I'm still on promises (waiting for the current version of Node to support async await). I don't have any insight into why that's happening. But good luck to you brother.

Comment: Yes if your function returns a promise and you do not put "await" before calling it in a try/catch block then it will never go into the catch block for some reason. They need to let us mark try/catches as async because needing two different syntaxes `.catch(error =>` and `try {...} catch (error) {}` is dumb

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular try catch to catch the error instead of .catch()

```
var dates;
try {
    dates = await this.props.uiStore
        .loadAvailableDates(endDate, startDate, managedParcel.bounds)
} catch {
    dates = [];
}
return dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise...

[Check out advenced example here with .catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)